# Paypal express checkout address fields empty

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express

We have PayPal expresss checkout enabled in M2 shop.

In few cases there have been missing information from shipping address.

- customer name has been firstname field (both firstname and lastname) and lastname empty
- zip code has been empty
- phone number has been empty.

I tried testing this, but was simply not able to create an address in PayPal with missing information.

How come this is possible? What could be the reason Magento accepts the address with missing fields?

Answer (score -1):

Refresh your cart multiple times at checkout